# How to install Panda3d on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS install

Tags: software-installation

I recently learned python and so I want to code a game. I was finding a engine that allows me to code/script in python and so I came across panda3d.
In the internet there was many guides to install it on windows however I am using Ubuntu and so I got tutorial that said how to install it in Ubuntu however they made no use.Please help how do I get panda 3d installed on my Ubuntu PC.
The version of Ubuntu I am using is 18.04 .

Answer (score 1):

You can install it using pip
`python3 -m pip install --extra-index-url https://archive.panda3d.org/ panda3d`

Answer (score 1):

he easiest way to install the latest development build of Panda3D into an existing Python installation is using the following commands:

```
sudo apt install python-pip  
sudo -H pip2 install --upgrade pip 
pip install --pre --extra-index-url https://archive.panda3d.org/ panda3d
```

The archive at https://archive.panda3d.org/ contains binaries for all currently supported versions of Ubuntu.